# Why we need to mention the scalar product of $\cos (nx), \sin (nx)$?

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, motivation

I found the following text -

> The functions $\cos (nx), n = 0, 1, 2, \cdots$ and $\sin (nx), n = 1, 2, \cdots $ which are known to be orthogonal with respect to the
> standard scalar product on $(-\pi, \pi)$.

The source of the problem is  -

[image]

**Question:** Plz explain why we author needed to mention
"..the functions $\cos (nx), n = 0, 1, 2, \cdots$ and $\sin (nx), n = 1, 2, \cdots $ which are known to be orthogonal with respect to the standard scalar product on $(-\pi, \pi)$".... as we dont need the scalar product of  $\cos (nx),  \sin (nx)$ in the above example?

**Note:**

We are doing scalar product of $f$ and  $\sin nx$, scalar product of $f$ and $\cos nx$, scalar product of $\sin nx$ and $\sin nx$, scalar product of $\cos nx$ and $\cos nx$, but we never used scalar product of $\cos nx$ and $\sin nx$, then why it was mentioned? what is the meaning of that part of the sentence?
Thanks.

Comment: The link of the  text is (go to page 10) : https://www.math.usm.edu/math/lambers/mat415/lecture1.pdf

Comment: They're deriving $b_n$ using that orthogonality, right? The same can be done with the $a_n$, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that

$$f\left(x\right) = a_0 +\sum _{n=1}^\infty \left(a_n\cos nx+b_n\sin nx\right)$$
We get the expression for $b_n$ as follows
$$\left\langle f\vert \sin mx \right\rangle = \sum _{n=1}^\infty  \left\langle \left(a_n\cos nx+b_n\sin nx\right)\vert \sin mx \right\rangle$$
$$=b_m\left\langle \sin mx\vert \sin mx \right\rangle$$
Using both that $\left\langle \sin mx\vert \sin nx \right\rangle=0$ for $n\neq m$ and that $\left\langle \sin mx\vert \cos nx \right\rangle=0$, i.e. that sin and cos are orthogonal.

Comment: but we already know $a_n=0$, don't need  $\left\langle \sin mx\vert \cos nx \right\rangle=0$

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: It is is written on text (see the attached image), I have a separate proof for that...

Comment: The text says that this follows as $f$ is an odd function. Ask yourself what exactly the argument is from $f$ being odd to $a_n=0$. You will find that you need the formula for $a_n$ and that formula is derived using orthogonality as in my answer

Comment: $a_n=0$ because, $\langle\cos nx | f \rangle=\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x) \cos nx \; dx=0,$ thus, $a_n = \frac{\langle \cos nx |f\rangle}{\langle \cos nx |\cos nx\rangle}=\frac{0}{\pi}=0$, here $f(x)=x$

Answer (score 1):

The scalar product *is* used right after, when the author writes$$b_n=\frac{\langle\sin nx|f\rangle}{\langle\sin nx|\sin nx\rangle}.$$

Comment: we are doing scalar product of $ f$ and $\ sin nx$, scalar product of $f $and $\cos nx$, scalar product of $\sin nx$ and $\sin nx$, scalar product of $\cos nx $and $\cos nx$, but we never used scalar product of $\cos nx$ and $\sin nx$, then why it was mentioned? what is the meaning of that part of the sentence?

Comment: @Andrew: check the expression of $f$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust why i need see the expansion? note that due to odd $f(x), a_n=0$ already...../

Answer (score 0):

We do in fact need the scalar product of $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$. Suppose we want to take a Fourier series of $\sin(mx)$ ($m\in \mathbb{N}$). We know, based on the definition, that $a_n=0 ~\forall n$, and $b_n=1$ if $n=m$ or $0$ otherwise. Thus,
$$a_n=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(mx)\cos(nx)\mathrm{d}x$$
In order for consistency, this needs to be $=0$ $\forall n$, or in other words, we need $\sin(mx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ to be orthogonal.

Comment: Lost from "and $b_n =1$ if $n=m$ or $0$ otherwise....." and the remaining part ...

Comment: Well, how do you express $\sin(5x)$ as a sum of sines and cosines? The sum only has one term: $\sin(5x)$. So all cosine coefficients ($a_n$s) are zero, and $b_n=1$ if $n=5$, but all other sine coefficients are zero.

Comment: Plz go to the page 10, $b_n$ is not $1$.... but I get why u misunderstood that  my point is the $a_n$ u used is not required in the example, then why they mentioned it?